# Multi level menu with TWIG no work

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to create a multi level menu in twig

Can you give me an example based on my code?

The first menu works normal, I heard about having to use macros, but I do not know how it works

look:
.twig:

```
<ul class="header_desktop_categories_ul">
            {% if cat_pai_desktops %}
                {% for cat_pai_desktop in cat_pai_desktops %}
                <li>
                    <a href='{{constant('BASE')}}/produtos/{{cat_pai_desktop.cat_name}}' title='{{cat_pai_desktop.cat_title}}'>{{cat_pai_desktop.cat_title}}</a>
                    {% if cat_filha_desktops %}
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            {% for cat_filha_desktop in cat_filha_desktops %}
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{constant('BASE')}}/produtos/{{cat_filha_desktop.cat_name}}" title="{{cat_filha_desktop.cat_title}}">{{cat_filha_desktop.cat_title}}</a></li>

                                {% if cat_subfilha_desktops %}
                                {% for cat_subfilha_desktop in cat_subfilha_desktops %}
                                <li><a href="{{constant('BASE')}}/produtos/{{cat_subfilha_desktop.cat_name}}" title="{{cat_subfilha_desktop.cat_title}}">{{cat_subfilha_desktop.cat_title}}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
```

php:

```
 $Read->FullRead("SELECT cat_id, cat_title, cat_name FROM " . DB_PDT_CATS . " WHERE cat_parent IS NULL ORDER BY cat_title ASC");
if ($Read->getResult()):
    $cat_pai_desktop = $Read->getResult();
    foreach ($Read->getResult() as $SES):
        $Read->FullRead("SELECT cat_id, cat_title, cat_name FROM " . DB_PDT_CATS . " WHERE cat_parent = :cat ORDER BY cat_title ASC", "cat={$SES['cat_id']}");
        if ($Read->getResult()):
            $cat_filha_desktop = $Read->getResult();
            foreach ($Read->getResult() as $CAT):
                $Read->setPlaces("cat={$CAT['cat_id']}");
                if ($Read->getResult()):
                    $cat_subfilha_desktop = $Read->getResult();
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

And:

```
print $twig->render('header.twig', array(
    'cat_pai_desktops' => $cat_pai_desktop,
    'cat_filha_desktops' => $cat_filha_desktop,
    'cat_subfilha_desktops' => $cat_subfilha_desktop
));
```

But this is not working right

Comment: What issue are you getting. Please be more specific about the error you are getting.

Comment: The problem is that the first menu works, but the sub menu is the same on every first menu

Comment: Look: https://i.imgur.com/OK5LHJD.png

Comment: Please refer to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239995/how-to-create-dynamic-menu-with-sub-menu-with-php-mysql

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman 
I'm using the twig, I use using php only, it would work

Comment: @DarkBee 
I saw this post but I did not quite understand it

Comment: How do u save u'r menu and their relationship with their children?