# How to make menu as dynamic based on table values in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

The following table contain main menu and sub menu into a same column.I mentioned `menu_root_id` for `submenu` based on `menu_code` to differentiate `main_menu` and `submenu`. 
I need to display all `submenu` under `mainmenu` based on the table dynamically into the following HTML menu code. Please help me how to do this?

[image]

This my html static Menu code:

```
         <!-- sidebar menu -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
            <li class="nav-devider"></li>
            <li class="header nav-small-cap"></li>

            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
                <span>Main Menu1</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="">Sub menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub menu2</a></li>            
                <li><a href="">Sub menu3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

             <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span>Main Menu2</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="">Sub menu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub menu5</a></li>            
                <li><a href="">Sub menu6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

This my Dynamic code:but it displays improperly.

```
                          <!-- sidebar menu -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
            <li class="nav-devider"></li>
            <li class="header nav-small-cap"></li>
              <?php
                    $query =  $this->db->get('create_menu');
                    $this->db->order_by("menu_order_no", "asc");
                        if($query -> num_rows() > 0){
                            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                                 ?>
                <li class="treeview">
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
                        <span><?php if($row['menu_root_id'] == "")
                                 {  echo $row['menu_name']; }
                             ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                        </span>
                      </a>

                      <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <?php ?> <li><a href=""><?php print_r($row['menu_name']); ?></a></li><?php  ?>
                      </ul>
                </li>
                    <?php   } }  ?>             
         </ul>
```

Comment: Show what you've tried..

Comment: You should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239995/how-to-create-dynamic-menu-with-sub-menu-with-php-mysql). Here you can find your requirement.

Comment: @YashParekh i updated my code..

Comment: Is it for a real website or just an exercice? Because this way of working doesn't looks very "flexible" if you need to add a new submenu for example. I think it would be better to have multiple table for main menu and sub menu, but with your approach you should work with some PHP to be sure to get all data in right order

Comment: It is just excercise task@Mickael Leger...

Comment: @sunshine If it's an exercice, you should do it alone if you are learning :) And if it's an exercice, you the goal is to have the good result no matter what? If yes, you can "cheat" and just display the menu according to `menu_order` : you know that menu_order 1 is Main and have menu_order 2- 3-4 as sub, and menu_order 5 is Main with submenu 6-7-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
  <li class="nav-devider"></li>
  <li class="header nav-small-cap"></li>
  <?php
    // Get here all the main menu's in $query by having the condition that menu_root_id=null
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
  ?>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
      <span><?php echo $row['menu_name']; ?></span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <?php
        // Get here all the sub menu's in $query1 by having the condition that menu_root_id=$row['menu_code']
        if($query1->num_rows() > 0) {
          foreach ($query1->result_array() as $row1) {
      ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $row1['menu_path']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['menu_name']; ?></a></li>
      <?php
          }
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Simple. Basic idea is to get all the main menu's first then loop over it. After that loop over sub menu's and get the name with link.
I don't know about CI. So I left the query area as comment.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you get menu code when menu root id null then you get menu code then you can get related menu code result according to me

code like that
select menu code from table name where menu root id null

then

select * from table name where menu root id = menu code

i think you apply this approach once